# set array back to first mysqli result

Tags: php, for-loop, mysqli

I am trying to return an array to first state after getting mysql results. 
Mysql results give me numbers from 30 to 110.

After for loop and if there is no more numbers after 110, I am trying to **set array back to 30** ( or index 0). Is there any way to set this?
Also I tried to set to 0, but it gives me nothing.

```
$uzmi_podstanice = "SELECT  *  FROM objekt WHERE vrsta_objekta = '2' ORDER BY sifra ASC";
                    $pronasao_sve_podstanice = $db->query($uzmi_podstanice);
                    while($rowss = $pronasao_sve_podstanice->fetch_assoc()) {
                        $svaka_sifra[] = $rowss['sifra'];
                    }


$pocetni_datum_vrti = new DateTime($sutrasnji_datum);
$zavrsni_datum_vrti = new DateTime($datum_prestanka);
$x = 0;
$i = 0;
$kkk = 0;
$hhh = 0;

for($q = $pocetni_datum_vrti; $q <= $zavrsni_datum_vrti; $q->modify('+1 day')){
                    $rezultat_datuma = $q->format("Y-m-d");

    for ($i=0; $i < $podstanice_prijepodne; $i++) { 
        if(isset($svaka_sifra[$kkk])){ // kontroliraj postoji li taj broj podstanice
            if($podstanice_prijepodne >= $i) {


                $values = "('$rezultat_datuma', '$svaka_sifra[$kkk]')PRIJEPODNE" . "<br />";
                $kkk++;
                echo $values;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        } else { //IF THERE IS MORE NUMBERS AFTER 110 CONTROLE THIS
            // trying to set $svaka_sifra to index 0 back
        }
    }

    for ($x=0; $x < $podstanice_poslijepodne; $x++) {
        if(isset($svaka_sifra[$kkk])){
            if($podstanice_poslijepodne >= $x) {

                $values2 = "('$rezultat_datuma', '$svaka_sifra[$kkk]')POSLJEPODNE" . "<br />";
                $kkk++;
                echo $values2;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        } else { // IF THERE IS MORE NUMBERS AFTER 110 CONTROLE THIS
            echo "no more results"; // trying to set $svaka_sifra to index 0 back
        }
    }

}
```

This should work for every date, I tried to control it to come back to the loop, set it to go from scratch..

Comment: Sorry, i have no idea what you are asking. can you be more specific and provide a simple minified example of your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant set the array variable $svaka_sifra to 0 because you will override the variable value.

You shoud just change the index value, in your case the $kkk, to zero.

```
$kkk = 0
```